# How To update run time resources,configurations,website and backend in aws using php sdk Api 2015-10-01

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am creating Ec2 instance dash board, so i have to update the configurations, resource, website, backend e-g http:\[ip]:8000\update-resource, I don't know how to update and what functions are should be used.Can anyone please help me